# not able to push the repo to Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-nodejs

I'm getting

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
```

when I try to push to Heroku , this is not a first push I have this app deployed in Heroku already, but all of a sudden Heroku started throwing this error.

I have tried

- setting `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`
- restarting all `dynos`
- deleting Heroku project and creating it again.
- tried pushing same repo to GitHub and it works fine.

I'm using macos-catalina

here is the complete error

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.18.3
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.6
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case any one is facing similar issues , check Heroku logs , in my case `next.js` build was taking too much memory so the deploy was getting rejected, eventhough push was success.